# How to Set a HashMap from jsp to Action

Tags: java, jsp, dictionary, struts2, hashmap

I have a HashMap in my Action class:

```
private Map<String, String> ids = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

In jsp I'm trying to set this hashmap like this:

```
<input type="text" name="ids[0].key" value="key">
<input type="text" name="ids[0]" value="value">
```

But when after submit, when I iterate over the map in the action like this:

```
if(ids!=null){
    for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : ids.entrySet()){
        system.out.println(entry.getKey()+"-"+entry.getValue());
    }
}
```

I only get "0-value" instead of "key-value"

How Can I do what I want? Can someone help me with this?

Comment: How do you retrieve ids after submit?

Comment: Hashmapping to textfields almost the same like lists or collection. Use indexed property names and make sure `createIfNull` is enabled.

Comment: @SyamS through a <s:form>

Comment: @RomanC I don't understand what you say with "indexed property names and make sure createIfNull is enabled". And I want to do textfields to Hashmap..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have keys of type `String` and therefore should be mapped like strings. For example

```
<input type="text" name="ids['0']" value="%{value}">
```

Then you will get key `'0'` and value that was provided by OGNL.

About indexed property names and `createIfNull` setting you can find in the docs [Advanced Type Conversion](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/type-conversion.html#advanced-type-conversion).

Comment: Ok I already see what I was doing wrong. For what I want I needed a Map<String, List<String>> and you made me see that. Thank you ;) and your answer is still correct!

Comment: Don't use collections inside collections. This doesn't work. Always use a collection inside a bean.

Comment: "Don't use collections inside collections" - Why? "This doesn't work" - but it worked and I already can set the map trough the jsp..

Comment: @tviana Could you provide the example? Because I don't understand what are you talking precisely.

Comment: ok, lets assume that on my jsp I have the following textfields:
    <input type="text" name="ids[0]" value="2">
    <input type="text" name="ids[0]" value="1">
    <input type="text" name="ids[1]" value="2">
    <input type="text" name="ids[1]" value="3">

and in the action I have a Map<Integer, List<String>>, after I submit the textfields, when I iterate I got the values correctly matched

    for(Map.Entry<Integer, List<String>> entry : ids.entrySet()){
 for(String id : entry.getValue()){
     system.out.println(entry.getKey+"-"id);
 }
    }

Output :
0-2
0-1
1-2
1-3

Comment: I could guess that it could work, but you didn't use indexed access to the list elements. They are converted to list or array because have the same name. The order is not guaranteed, and such fields aren't mapped correctly. To map fields by name to access a list by index you have to provide the index of the element that gets the correct element from the list. And I don't think it will work with other collections.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to set values in a `HashMap` in a JSP file is a very bad idea. To stick with best practice and lead a happy life, you should revisit your design. You can post the data to the server side (All input values from JSP) and then get the values from request to store in a `HashMap` collection as per your requirement would be a better option.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. "Trying to set values in a HashMap in a JSP file is a very bad idea" why? And I'm not using scriplets right?

Comment: I'm sorry misunderstood it

Comment: I do not see any problem to set a HashMap from JSP. You can later validate that hashmap and lead a happy life :)