# How to create a hash map in java script and send the hash map to java action class

Tags: javascript, java, hashmap, duplicates, hidden-field

I have text boxes like which will have some values and i would like to create a hash map with no duplicates and send that hash map to action class.

```
    <input type="text" name="test1" value="test" /> 
    <input type="text" name="test2" value="test2" />
```

Like the above there will be `N` number of text boxes and create a `hash map key as name of the text box and value as the value of the text box`

would some one help me as how to do this please.

Comment: may be this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23827599/how-to-set-a-hashmap-from-jsp-to-action

Comment: This might help you make a HashMap in JS: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/368280/javascript-hashmap-equivalent)

Comment: There is no need for JavaScript, to do so. Just post the form to a servlet.

Comment: @Stefan The text boxes are not static and they are dynamic that is the reason why i dont post the form if not that could be the best option.

Comment: It does not matter how they are created.

Comment: @Stefan sorry forgot to mention that i am using struts, is it not true that struts form expect the fields name ?, would you please help as how to if Yes for struts

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://struts.apache.org/docs/processing-forms.html

Comment: @Stefan the above link wont be useful, thanks